# How do i get the output in one line as a string?

Tags: python, string, loops, ascii, capitalize

I wrote this bit of code in python to capitalize and print the first 4 characters of any string. But I am getting the output is:

```
A
P
P
L
```

The output i need is:

```
APPL
```

What changes should i make here then?

```
def capital(uinput):
    slice4 = uinput[:4]
    for i in slice4:
       j = ord(i)
       j = j - 32
       k = chr(j)
       print k

print capital("apple")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `upper()`?

```
>>> s = "apple"
>>> s[:4]
'appl'
>>> s[:4].upper()
'APPL'
```

Speaking about the code you've written, you can modify it this way to make it work:

```
def capital(uinput):
    slice4 = uinput[:4]
    result = ""
    for i in slice4:
       j = ord(i)
       j = j - 32
       k = chr(j)
       result += k
    print result
```

or, the same but in one line without having additional variables:

```
def capital(uinput):
    print "".join([chr(ord(i) - 32) for i in uinput[:4]])
```